# mysqli query returning wrong values

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm making a function which returns the requested fields of certain user connected to a user ID, my current code is this:

```
<?php
    function getUserData($id = "current", $field = "username"){
        global $database;
        if($id == "current"){
            $id = $_SESSION['userID'];
        }
        $query = $database->prepare("SELECT :field FROM `users` WHERE `ID` = :ID LIMIT 1;");
        $query->bindParam(":ID",$id);
        $query->bindParam(":field",$field);
        $query->execute();
        while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)){
            print_r($row);
        }
        //return $username;
    }
?>
```

if the `$id` value is kept empty it looks for the currently logged in ID, which works fine. Same for the `$field` if that is empty, it looks just for the username connected to the ID the problem is in the 
`$query->bindParam("field",$field);` .. for some reason this does not work and while using this the print_r returns this:

`Array ( [username] => username [0] => username )`

while the exact same query works when using it like this:

`$query = $database->prepare("SELECT $field FROM`users`WHERE`ID`= :ID LIMIT 1;");`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: bindParam would treat field as variable and add ' around value. and you cant use single quote for column or table name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're binding a field name, so your query will become like this:

```
SELECT 'username' FROM `users` WHERE `ID` = 'X' LIMIT 1;
```

This won't work, you can't bind a field name like this. you will have to pass field names as php variables directly without binding them.

Check out this: [Can PHP PDO Statements accept the table or column name as parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-name-as-parameter)

It might help you.

Comment: so basicly `$database->prepare("SELECT $field FROM users WHERE ID= :ID LIMIT 1;");` would be my way to go?

Comment: @Azrael yes that would be your way to go, you can add some php checks to make sure the fields received actually exist in the table, that's not to face errors with wrong column names.

Comment: The field exists for sure ;) Thanks for your awnser! will mark it once I can ;)

Comment: @Azrael Yes it all depends on where you're getting the field name from. if it is hard coded then you don't need testing, if it is entered by a user or something of this sort, then you'll need checks.

Comment: the `$field` value is going to be hardcoded, and the `$id` is dynamic, when left empty it will use the currently logged in ID, otherwise it will use the provided `$id`